# Ajax calling controller to send a html table of objects form from view

Tags: c#, html-table, asp.net-mvc-5

What I am trying is to send a complex object from a view to controller. This object is composed by objects from a html table.
 When I call to the controller with AJAX call, the list of the object is always null. I don't know what is wrong because I have checked other code on internet and I don't find any difference but something has to have. Thanks in advance.

Model

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    public List<string> CheckedControl { get; set; }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int CtrIndex { get; set; }
    public List<string> DdItems { get; set; }
    public List<string> LangList { get; set; }
    public List<string> DdMulti { get; set; }

}
```

Javascript and ajax

```
    function ajaxSubmit() {
        var table_parameters = [[],[]];
        table_parameters = getSchemaTableData();
        var projectName = document.getElementById('txtProjectName').value;
        var projectID = document.getElementById('txtProjectID').value;


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ControlsCreation", "Projects")",
            dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Parameters: table_parameters, ProjectName: projectName,   ProjectID: projectID }),

            success: function (data) { alert(data); },

        failure: function (errMsg) {
                            alert(errMsg);
                        }
                    });

    }
```

and the controller

```
   public JsonResult ControlsCreation(List<Models.Parameter> Parameters, string ProjectName, string ProjectID)
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] == null) return Json("Home/Index");
        string userID = Session["UserID"] as string;


        var mngService = new DBManager(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Bugmania2019"].ConnectionString);
        DBLogic dbAccess = new DBLogic(mngService);

        ViewModels.ParametersTable viewModel = new ViewModels.ParametersTable()
        {
            ParametersCollection = Parameters,
            ProjectName = ProjectName,
            ProjectID = ProjectID
        };

        dbAccess.UpdateControls(viewModel);

        return Json("Success!");
    }
```

I have modified the controller, view and model. I would appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this alternative way to send your request via `AJAX` to `Controller` method:

AJAX call:

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    var table_parameters = [[],[]];
    table_parameters = getSchemaTableData();
    var projectName = document.getElementById('txtProjectName').value;
    var projectID = document.getElementById('txtProjectID').value;

    var json = {
       table_parameters : table_parameters,
       projectName : projectName,
       projectID : projectID
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ControlsCreation", "Projects")",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function (data) { alert(data); }
        ,
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });

}
```

And your `Controller` method will look like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ControlsCreation(string json)
{
  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

  //Get your variables here from AJAX call
  var table_parameters = jsondata["table_parameters"];
  var projectName = jsondata["projectName"];
  var projectID = jsondata["projectID"];

        if (Session["UserID"] == null) return Json("Home/Index");
        string userID = Session["UserID"] as string;

        var mngService = new DBManager(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Bugmania2019"].ConnectionString);
        DBLogic dbAccess = new DBLogic(mngService);

        ViewModels.ParametersTable viewModel = new ViewModels.ParametersTable()
        {
            ParametersCollection = Parameters,
            ProjectName = ProjectName,
            ProjectID = ProjectID
        };

        dbAccess.UpdateControls(viewModel);

        return Json("Success!");
}
```